# Multiple Features in LSTM Keras

Tags: python-3.x, lstm, keras-layer

I have multiple features to be used in LSTM with timesteps = 5 (n), when i run the model

```
def create_dataset(dataset, time_stamp=5):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    print(len(dataset) - time_stamp - 1)
    for i in range(len(dataset) - time_stamp - 1):
        a = dataset[i:(i + time_stamp), :]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + time_stamp, 0])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)


model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(16,activation="relu",input_shape=(timeFrame,2), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='relu'))
model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss='mean_squared_error')
model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=30, batch_size=1, verbose=1)

X_train.shape = (8,5,2) // The data sets have 8 different datasets with 5 timesteps and 2 features
Y_train.shape =  (8)    // 


train_predict = model.predict(X_train)
```

train_predict.shape = (8,5,1)

when i try to do So this works fine ... now the problem is that when i run the following

```
scaler.inverse_transform(train_predict) //{ValueError}Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.

scaler.inverse_transform(Y_train) //geting error
```

the issue is both have different dimension as two input feature is getting mapped with 1 feature. So inverse_transform does not work properly. How to fix this problem

goal is to find mse

```
[math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(Y_train, train_predict))]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post the full error traceback.